# Using telnet of server A to connect to other ports at server B

Tags: port, telnet

Is using telnet server of Server A to connect to other ports at server B possible?

If this is possible, can anyone show me how to do syntax?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> it's like Machine Z (my machine) - Machine A (where telnet server is located at) - Machine B (port some number) *– Lanz*

No, the Telnet protocol is very simple and does not have anything like SSH's "tcpip-forward"; it only supports a single interactive terminal.

(It might be possible to write a program to implement something similar on top of Telnet, but it would be much more trouble than it's worth, not to mention insecure. Use SSH instead.)